# The latest Emacs initialization hook

Tags: hooks, start-up, exwm

I am currently running Emacs as a desktop with EXWM.
And I am trying to run some apps on startup to see them in a EXWM's systemtray:

```lisp
(defun run-auto-start ()
   (start-process-shell-command "pnmixer" nil "/bin/pnmixer")
   (start-process-shell-command "nm-applet" nil "/bin/nm-applet"))
```

I have attached this function to `exwm-init-hook`. But it seems that it is too early for a system tray to work properly, because sometimes these apps do not appear in a systemtray or only one of them does. (I initialize systemtray with `(exwm-systemtray-enable)` before attaching the function to the hook) However if I evaluate those two lines manually after Emacs finished loading, `pn-mixer` and `nm-applet` immediately launch and go to the system tray.

So what is the last Emacs initialization hook I can use to execute my shell commands as late as possible to avoid running them manually? Maybe there is some hack to emulate this kind of "late hook"?..

P.S. I have tries `after-init-hook` and `emacs-startup-hook` none of them work well

Comment: I launch `nm-applet` from my `.xsession` *before* firing `emacs` and so `exwm`.  The app appears in the `exwm` sys-tray just fine.

Comment: (Untested) Make sure that you enable the systemtray (with `exwm-systemtray-enable`) *before* you add your function to `exwm-init-hook` and make sure that you add your function to the hook with a `DEPTH` parameter of 100 to make sure that it is added *after* the systemtray init function that `exwm-systemtray-enable` adds. Check the value of `exwm-init-hook` to make sure you have done it correctly.

Comment: Fran, didn't work for me, anyway I wanted to have some portable solution inside of my Emacs config, so that I do not need to borrow X configs to run Emacs on another machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Startup Summary` <kbd>RET</kbd>

> P.S. I have tries `after-init-hook` and `emacs-startup-hook` none of them work well

The only startup hook which runs after `emacs-startup-hook` is `window-setup-hook`:

```
This is very similar to ‘emacs-startup-hook’.  The only difference
is that this hook runs after frame parameters have been set up in
response to any settings from your init file.  Unless this matters
to you, use ‘emacs-startup-hook’ instead.  (The name of this hook
is due to historical reasons, and does not reflect its purpose
very well.)
```

If that (`window-setup-hook`) doesn't work either, you could use one of the startup hooks to start a timer via `run-with-timer`, so that your code runs after some brief delay.

Comment: But EXWM still starts up after ```emacs-startup-hook```, so ```exwm-init-hook``` runs after ```window-setup-hook```? ```run-with-timer``` solved the problem ! thanks